# A certain topology defined by using Euclidean topology

Tags: general-topology, connectedness

Define a family of subsets of $X=\Bbb R^n$ by the following.

$F \in {\cal F} \iff F$ is $\emptyset$ or  $\Bbb R^n$ or a bounded closed subset of with respect to the [Euclidean topology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_topology).

> (1) Show that ${\cal F}$ satisfies the axioms of closed sets. (So ${\cal F}$ defines a topology.)

I could have checked all of the axioms except the one that ${\cal F}$ is closed under finite union. We need to show that $$V:=\bigcup_{i=1}^n V_i\in {\cal F} \quad\forall V_i\in {\cal F}.$$ 
We can assume that $V_i \ne \emptyset$ for all $i$. If there exists $V_k$ so that $V_k=X$ then $V=X\in {\cal F}$. For otherwise,
$$X-V = X-\left(\bigcup_{i=1}^n V_i\right)=\bigcap_{i=1}^n\left(X-V_i\right)$$
is open since $X-V_i$ is open for all $i$. What's left is to prove $V$ is bounded. I want to find a ball $B_r(x) \subset X$ so that $V \subset B_r(x)$. I can imagine its existence since $V_i \subset B_{r_i}(x_i)$ for some $r_i>0, x_i\in X$ but cannot find any appropriate candidate.

Let $T$ denote the topological space $(\Bbb R^n, {\cal F})$.

> (2) Show that $T$  is not a Hausdorff space.

Suppose to the contrary that $T$ is a Hausdorff space. Then for all $x,y\in T$ we can find $U, V \in {\cal F}$ such that $x\in U, y\in V$ and $U \cap V =\emptyset$. I don't whether I'm on the right path but there's no contradiction comes out yet.

> (3) Show that $T$  is connected.

I was completely lost at this point.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Hint: do you have an intuitive idea what the open sets of your space look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT: A set $A\subseteq\Bbb R^n$ is bounded if and only if there is an $r>0$ such that $A\subseteq B(\mathbf{0},r)$, where $\mathbf{0}$ is the origin. This makes it easy to show that a finite union of bounded sets is bounded.

For the other two parts, note that if $F\in\mathscr{F}$ and $F\ne\Bbb R^n$, then $F$ is compact in the usual topology on $\Bbb R^n$. (Why?) Use this observation to show that if $U$ and $V$ are non-empty open sets in this new topology on $\Bbb R^n$, then $U\cap V\ne\varnothing$; both $(2)$ and $(3)$ then follow easily.

Comment: Thanks to your hint the finite union is bounded by a ball $B_r(0)$ with $r=\max\{r_i\mid 1 \le i\le n\}$. Can you give me some evidence of your hint?

Comment: @user: That’s how I define *bounded*. What definition are you using?

Comment: I used the definition that a subset $V$ is bounded if it is contained in a ball of finite radius according to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bounded_set.

Comment: @user: Let $x=\langle x_1,\ldots,x_n\rangle\in\Bbb R^n$ and $r>0$. If $\|x\|=\sqrt{x_1^2+\ldots+x_n^2}$, you can easily show that $B(x,r)\subseteq B(\mathbf{0},\|x\|+r)$, so the two definitions are equivalent.

Comment: About your second question, $F$ is compact because $F$ is either $\emptyset$ or a closed and bounded set. But I don't see why $U \cap V \ne \emptyset$?

Comment: @user: You know that there are $F,G\in\mathscr{F}$ such that $U=\Bbb R^n\setminus F$ and $V=\Bbb R^n\setminus G$. If $U\cap V=\varnothing$, what can you say about $F\cup G$?

Comment: Oh, you mean if $U$ and $V$ are non-empty open sets in this new topology then there are $F,G\in {\cal F}$ such that $U=F^c, V=G^c$? If that, then $F\cap G=T$ follows from $U \cap V=\emptyset$. But this is a contradiction since $T$ is infinite. I made a mistake from the beginning by thinking that if $U$ is open in $T$ then $U\in {\cal F}$ while it should be $U^c \in {\cal F}$.

Comment: @user: (I assume that $F\cap G=T$ was a typo for $F\cup G=T$.) Yes, that’s the key, though the problem isn’t that $T$ is infinite: it’s that $F\cup G$ is compact in the usual topology, and $T$ isn’t.

Comment: The finite union of compact sets is compact and your explanation works perfectly here. Why the fact that $T$ is infinite can be used to obtain contradiction?

Comment: @user: It can’t. That’s why I said that the problem is *not* that $T$ is infinite. The problem is that it is unbounded and therefore not compact in the usual topology.

Comment: Ahh, my bad. I was thinking about "unboundedness" of $T$ while my hands typed "infinite" :( Now I understand why you said the part (3) is also straightforward. Because if $T$ is not connected, it can  be divided into two disjoint nonempty closed sets, say $T=F\cup G$ with $F, G \in {\cal F}$. Again we obtain a contradiction as before.

Comment: @user: Yes, that’s right: now you’ve got it.